# Proof of the union of two power sets $(P(A) \cup P(B))$ is subset of $P(A \cup B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an intuitive understanding of the proof, but I can't figure out how to prove the above statement without relying on giving each set some numbers. I mean that I'd like to learn how to prove mathematical statements (including this one) using mathematical language.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $C \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$. This means that $C \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ or $C \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. If the first is the case, then $C \subseteq A$ by definition. So also, as $A \subseteq A \cup B$, $C \subseteq A \cup B$ and so $C \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$. Else $C \in \mathcal{P}(B)$ so $C \subseteq B$ and again $C \subseteq A \cup B$ and so $C \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.

So all members of the left hand union set are in the right hand set, and the inclusion has been shown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just one minor issue: by the last point, we conclude that C is an element and isn't less than or equal to the power set of the union of A and B simply because we're no longer dealing with the union on its own but rather with its power set, is that right?

Comment: @Jobran I don't get your question. There is no "less than or equal" just "subset or equal ($\subseteq$)". I use the definition: $C \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ iff $C \subseteq A$. The elements of the powerset of $A$ are exactly the subsets of $A$.

Comment: Subset or equal is precisely what I meant, but it didn't come to mind. I supposed a set all elements of which are included in another set (superset) could be considered smaller than said superset. If I'm not mistaken, the power set of a union has to be larger / include more elements than the union itself.

Comment: @Jobran Of course the union of the power sets can be smaller than the power set of the union: if $x \in A, x \notin B$ exists and also $y \in B, y \notin A$, then $\{x,y\}$ is not a subset of $A$, nor of $B$, but is a member of $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$, to give an example.

Comment: Thanks again, now I got the hang of it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ \quad X \in P(A) \cup P(B) \quad$ is arbitrary element.
$$ X \in P(A) \cup P(B) \iff X \in P(A) \lor x \in P(B) \iff (X= U, U \subseteq A) \lor (X = V, V \subseteq B).$$
In case $X=U$, it is true $X \subseteq A$, as well as $X \subseteq A \cup B$. In other case, i.e. $X = V$, it is true $X \subseteq B$, but also $X \subseteq A \cup B$. In both cases we have $X \subseteq A \cup B$, or in other words $X \in P(A \cup B)$.

Comment: All Ok! I am new here at this community, in other words still slow with editing....

Comment: Thank you for your answer.